# how to get longitude and latitude from string in angular 4 typescript?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I am currently learning angular 4.and i ma using playing with google maps.
i was following this tutorial.
[google maps](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/)
i have successfully implemented it. 
but now situation is this, i have string of address in my database. like string is "London". i want to show marker on "london". can any body help me how can i get longitude and latitude of this specific string address. so that i can place marker at that position.
I have tried many tutorials but did not find any one that was converting string into longitude and latitude.
Please provide me any help.

let.

```
location="London"
longitutde:any;
latitude:any;

//how can i get these values in typescript?
```

I will be very thankful fr this favor.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method which uses the geocode to find the latitude and longitude from address

```
getLocation(address: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Getting address: ', address);
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocode();
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                observer.next(results[0].geometry.location);
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                console.log('Error: ', results, ' & Status: ', status);
                observer.error();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined, i am facing this error while calling.

Comment: add this to your index.html <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: what is the erorr now?

Comment: Its returning two functions and not latitude and longitude values. How to get the latitude and longitude values?

Comment: Also, is it `google.maps.Geocode()` or `google.maps.Geocoder()` ?